# Implementing the Google Drive File picker in iOS

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-picker

We are currently in the process of transitioning scopes for out app from the restricted 'auth/drive' scope to 'auth/drive.file' scope, however, it does not seem like the Google Drive Picker is prepared to render on a mobile device. The UI renders for desktop making it basically unusable in our native app. Is there a way to render it in a way that is responsive using a web view in an iOS app?

Google is asking us to migrate to a less sensitive scope and to use the picker but it seems there is no way to properly pick files and folders inside of a native mobile app. Currently we are using the drive scope and we have created a native picker ourselves. Is there a picker for mobile apps?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to render the Picker in a more mobile friendly way, it is not perfect but at least it is "somehow" more usable even though you need to still double-tap to enter a folder which is quite terrible. Anyways, I did this buy adding the following css style:

```
  .picker {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    top: 0 !important;
  }
```

And then adding this meta header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />
```

With this two changes the picker displays in full screen in the WKWebView that I'm using to load the picker and the UI is in a good size.

Still wishing for a solution from Google that does not require users to double tap on folders and to allow to create subfolders from the picker!

Comment: Thanks for sharing! We're trying to implement this on iOS/WKWebview and Android as part an Ionic app. I added a comment to your Google issue. 

For anyone else using Uppy, we're following the example at https://community.transloadit.com/t/to-use-google-drive-you-must-pass-googles-tier-2-security-assessment/16701/7.

Answer (score 0):

drive.file scope will only allow you to access files that your application created. Anything that is on the users drive that was created by another application you will not be able to access.

My understanding from [overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview) is that drive picker is for web applications it does not support mobile apps

it seems there may have been something eight years ago but its out of date [iOS-Swift-Google-Drive-Document-Picker](https://github.com/aytek/iOS-Swift-Google-Drive-Document-Picker)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We already have developed a custom made picker inside of our native app, the issue is that Google is now asking us to use the drive.file scope instead of the drive scope which is not sufficient for our picker to work as it needs to access all folders in Google Drive not only the ones created by our app. The annoying part is that Google does not provide a picker for native apps as you pointed out so we are totally stuck. We are still discussing with their team because ideally we just want to keep the current scopes as-is.

Comment: Email them back and explain your use case and tell them why you can't use that scope.   They are told to request you use less sensitive scopes it's up to you to advocate for your application and explain why you can't

Comment: Thanks. This is what we are trying to do now. Hopefully they will agree with our explanations.

Comment: Sadly after a few back and forth, Google is asking us to go through a CASA verification which seems extremely long and expensive for a team of our size. It seems our only option is to use the Google Drive Picker API but that does not work from iOS or Android. We are at a loss here. If you have any other ideas please let us know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. My plan is to create an internet page that implements the official picker, then on the mobile side have a webview that detects when any file is selected/downloaded.
I will report when it has been accepted or refused by Google.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I opened a issue about this on Google's issue tracker for Google Drive and hopefully that helps to get a mobile friendly version of the Picker. If you can add a comment to that issue hopefully it adds more weight so they can prioritise it faster: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/322267485